# Pegar uma sequencia de números na String

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso criar uma lógica para pegar uma sequencia de dígitos, provavelmente o ID do produto

A exemplo, produto:

```
YALE TP 12MM 582041250 MANGUEIRA 25mm x 30mm
```

Atualmente estou utilizando o código abaixo para descobrir os números da string, mas uma vez que há dados sujos, como medidas por exemplo minha busca se torna erronea:

```
desc_string2 ='YALE TP 12MM 582041250 MANGUEIRA 25mm x 30mm'
space_string2 = ''
for b in list(desc_string2):
    if(b.isdigit()):
        space_string2 += b
```

O retorno do meu código atual é:

```
125820412502530
```

Sendo a exemplo abaixo como eu gostaria de deixar:

```
582041250
```

Ou seja, pegar apenas uma sequencia especifica de caracteres

Obs: Não existe exatamente um critério e padrão nas strings, a ideia é pegar uma sequência de pelo menos 5 dígitos agrupados, sendo que não existe limite máximo de dígitos para os mesmos, ou seja, de '5 a n'.

Abaixo mais alguns exemplos de strings

String:

```
SENSOR INDUTI IM18 SICK IME18-05BPSZCOS
```

Deve retornar:

String:

```
TP 90091-0364 ANEL DE VEDACAO
```

Deve retornar:

```
900910364
```

String:

```
TP 6-9611 92 2226 KIT DA M5
```

Deve retornar:

```
69611922226
```

Comment: Mas qual o critério? É sempre uma sequência de 9 dígitos? Há a possibilidade de ter outras sequências de 9 dígitos, mas que não deveriam ser consideradas? Sempre aparece na mesma posição? Por exemplo, se for sempre a quarta palavra (assumindo que "palavras" são separadas por um espaço), nem precisaria de regex: https://ideone.com/uJImRQ

Comment: Não existe exatamente um critério e padrão nas strings, a idéia e pegar uma sequência de pelo menos 5 digitos agrupados unicamente.

Comment: Mas pode ter mais de uma sequência na mesma string? (caso tenha mais de uma, é pra retornar todas ou somente a primeira?) É no mínimo 5 dígitos, mas existe limite máximo? Note que, por mais que possam ter inúmeras variações, ainda sim são critérios :-) Sugiro [edit] a pergunta e colocar essas restrições, e talvez mais alguns exemplos de variações que a string pode ter

Comment: @hkotsubo realizei as adaptações sugeridas na pergunta. Pode verificar se está suficiente assim por favor?

Comment: Por que 25mm ou 12MM não considera, é só porque tem letras junto? A sequência só vale se entre os dígitos tiver hífen ou espaço, ou tem outros caracteres? Por exemplo, se for algo como `1-2/3 4.5,6`, tem que ser 123456?

Comment: Isso mesmo, por terem letras junto podemos entender que são unidades de medida, que por via de regra não fazem parte do ID do produto.

se for algo como 1-2/3 4.5,6, tem que ser 123456?
Exato!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138874/discussion-between-brandalize-and-hkotsubo).

Comment: Bom, pra mim parece estranho que "qualquer coisa" possa ser o código de produto (por exemplo, se tiver uma data como 10/08/2022, segundo seus critérios, isso pode ser confundido com um código válido), mas enfim, acho que seria isso: https://ideone.com/bXeWSp

Comment: @hkotsubo consegui com seu código, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O critério é bem amplo e sujeito a alguns problemas. Por exemplo, se tiver uma data como 10/08/2022, ou um CPF como 123.456.789-09, eles serão considerados como códigos válidos. Ou se tiver algo como uma frase que termina com número, e a frase seguinte começa com outro (por exemplo, "*... em 2022. 10 blabla...*",  `202210` também será considerado um código válido). E vários outros casos possíveis (afinal, estamos considerando que tudo que não é letra - espaços, hífens, pontos, etc - pode estar entre os dígitos), e muitas chances de falsos positivos.

Dito isso, sabendo desses problemas e limitações, uma solução seria iterar pelos caracteres da string e ir juntando os dígitos, exceto se estiverem juntos de uma letra. Qualquer coisa que não seja dígito ou letra é ignorado, algo assim:

```py
texto ='TP 6-9611 92 2226 KIT DA M5 12345mm a1b2 1.2-3 4/5;    6--  ..7 abc 12345 a 234 b'

result = []
previous = None
codigo = ''
for c in texto:
    # é dígito, e o caractere anterior não é letra
    if c.isdigit() and previous is not None and not previous.isalpha():
        codigo += c
    elif c.isalpha(): # é letra, provável fim de sequência
        # se tem uma sequência de pelo menos 5 dígitos e o anterior não é dígito
        if len(codigo) >= 5 and (previous is None or not previous.isdigit()):
            result.append(codigo) # código encontrado, adiciona na lista de resultados
        codigo = '' # começa um novo possível código
    # qualquer outro caractere (ponto, vírgula, hífen, espaço, etc) é ignorado

    previous = c

if len(codigo) > 5: # quando o código está no final da string, ele "sobra" ao final do loop
    result.append(codigo)
print(result) # ['69611922226', '1234567', '12345']
```

O resultado é uma lista contendo todos os códigos encontrados. No exemplo acima, é `['69611922226', '1234567', '12345']`.

---

Claro que também dá para fazer com regex, mas não sei se é mais simples:

```py
import re

def clean(s):
    return re.sub(r'\D', '', s)

texto ='TP 6-9611 92 2226 KIT DA M5 12345mm a1b2 1.2-3 4/5;    6--  ..7 abc 12345 a 234 b'

result = list(map(clean, re.findall(r'(?:(?<![a-z])[^\da-z]*\d[^\da-z]*(?![a-z])){5,}', texto, re.I)))
print(result)
```

Até tem menos linhas, mas olhe bem para o "pequeno monstrinho" que é a regex. Basicamente:

- `[a-z]` indica uma letra de "a" a "z" - e o uso da *flag* `re.I` faz com que ele considere tanto maiúsculas quanto minúsculas
- `[^\da-z]` é qualquer coisa que não seja dígito nem letra (alguém pode sugerir para usar `\W`, porém este atalho também exclui o caractere `_`, que eu entendi que pode estar entre os dígitos, portanto não é uma boa opção)
- o quantificador `*` indica "zero ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, os caracteres que não são dígitos nem letras (ex: espaço, hífen, vírgula, ponto, etc) podem se repetir várias vezes (ou nenhuma)
- `\d` é um dígito
- `(?<!` e `(?!` são *lookarounds* negativos, que verificam respectivamente se algo **não** existe antes ou depois.

Ou seja, a expressão pega um dígito, que pode ter zero ou mais caracteres antes e depois (que não são dígitos nem letras), e que antes ou depois não possuam letras.

Por fim, tudo isso pode se repetir 5 ou mais vezes (`{5,}`). Portanto, é uma sequência de pelo menos 5 dígitos, podendo ter entre eles ponto, espaço, vírgula, etc, e não podem ter letras antes nem depois.

Só que esta regex vai pegar os caracteres entre os dígitos também (espaços, hífens, etc), por isso eu precisei de outra regex (`\D` - tudo que não é digito) para removê-los, sobrando apenas os dígitos.

Veja que apesar de ser mais curto, não necessariamente é mais simples ou fácil de entender e manter. Já o `for`, apesar de "ter mais linhas", é mais simples de entender e modificar se for o caso.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar `regex` para efetuar essa busca.
Se você souber o padrão da informação o regex tende a facilitar por essa busca, por exemplo, se o número que você procura **SEMPRE** tem uma quantidade "x" de caracteres você pode buscar da seguinte maneira:

```
import re

content = re.findall(r"\d{9}", "YALE TP 12MM 582041250 MANGUEIRA 25mm x 30mm")

print(content) # saida: ['582041250']
print(content[0]) # saida: 582041250
```

- "\d" busca apenas por dígitos (números)
- {9} busca por exatamente 9 dígitos

Você também pode buscar por um intervalo de dígitos como, por exemplo, "entre 4 e 9 dígitos": {4,9}

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz uma solução totalmente diferente da sua. eu separei cada palavra em uma lista e pedi para varrer a lista atras de numeros.

```py
desc_string2 ='SENSOR INDUTI IM18 SICK IME18-05BPSZCOS'
lista = desc_string2.replace('-', ' ').split()
print(lista)
for i in range(0,len(lista)):
  t = 0
  if i < len(lista) - 1:
    if len(lista[i]) >= 5 and lista[i].isdigit():
        print(lista[i],end='')
        t = 1
    elif lista[i+1].isdigit():
      if lista[i].isdigit():
        print(lista[i],end='')
        t = 1
    elif lista[i+1].isdigit() == False and lista[i].isdigit():
      print(lista[i])
      t = 1
  else:
    if t == 1 and lista[i].isdigit():
      print(lista[i])
```

Funcionou para todos os casos que você pediu.

Se o número for maior ou igual a 5 ele vai imprimir na tela. Se o número for menor que 5 ele vai verificar se o proximo item da lista também é só números, caso sim ele imprimi o número.

são varios if e elif entretanto as suas especificações quanto ao critério são vagas então foi o melhor que eu pude fazer.

Answer (score -3):

Talvez o código abaixo funcione, ele cria uma lista separada por espaços em branco a partir da sua string e quando eu percorro no laço ele verifica se o item na lista só contém dígitos, veja abaixo:

```
desc_string2 ='YALE TP 12MM 582041250 MANGUEIRA 25mm x 30mm'
space_string2 = ''
for b in desc_string2.split():
  if(b.isdigit()):
    space_string2 += b
    
print(space_string2)
```